# How to launch default browser (e.g. Chrome) through bat script

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cmd.exe

I have a Chrome (default browser). I also have a bat script where I launch chrome with some flags.

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\dev\chrome-data --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating
```

How can I make this script a default for opening the Chrome? i.e. when I click on the links I want the chrome to be launched with this script.

Comment: Looks like your flags are disabling features you can access via chrome://settings/ so why not just change them there? You also have chrome://flags/ at your disposal.

Comment: Sound good. But on my Chrome 66, when I navigate to chrome://flags, I don't see this flags, e.g. when I type in search flags input disable-web-security or user-data-dir or disable-features